# Use FOR /R Parameter to set a variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to use a FOR /R command in a batch file to find all files with a particular extension (XMP). I then want to rename the extension to '*' to pass to ROBOCOPY. For my initial test, since I know * will need to be handled, I'm using ABC.

The problem is that I can't seem to get the value in %%G assigned to a variable for processing.

My code

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /R C:\Users\Paul\Pictures %%G IN (*.XMP) do (

set data="%%G"
set search=XMP
set replace=ABC
set "data=!data:%search%=%replace%!"

echo %data%
)
endlocal
```

Produces the following in one iteration

```
set data="C:\Users\Paul\Pictures\XXXX Family\YYYY\Shower\20160220_165255.xmp"
echo
set search=XMP
set replace=ABC  
set "data=!data:=!"
echo
)
```

How can I get the value in %GG assigned to 'data'?

Thanks

Comment: The search and replace variables would also need to use delayed expansion just like you are trying to do with the data variable. But you can't do double delayed expansion.  Put your search and replace variables before the FOR command.

Comment: Are you just trying to change the file extension?  If so, there is a SUPER easy way to do that if you read the help file for the `FOR` command.

Comment: Perhaps you could schedule this to run when my other half is asleep: `CopyAll -Now -Silent "%UserProfile%\Pictures\XXXX Family\YYYY\Shower\*.RAW" Compos-NAS` ;-)

Comment: Squashman, do you have a link to the example you mentioned? I check both DOS and Google but couldn't find one like you stated. Thanks.

Comment: Compu, unfortunately, the associated file with the XMP (from LightRoom) could have a NEF, ORD or JPG extension but all with the same file name.

Comment: Perhaps use modifiers i.e. `For /R C:\Users\Paul\Pictures %%G IN (*.XMP) do echo %%~dpnG.*`. This omits the extension so you can add your own. View `for /?` for help on modifiers. Also, advise read [Replying in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) about how to notify other commenters.

Comment: Thanks @michael_heath for the reference to 'Replying to Comments'.

The main problem is that the 'set data="%%G" doesn't assign anything to data.

Comment: If you use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` then try this example `For /R C:\Users\Paul\Pictures %%G IN (*.XMP) do (set "data=%%~dpnG") & echo "!data!"`. `"!data!"` will have drive, path and name without extension.

Comment: @DS256, you can read the help file for any command by opening a command prompt and typing the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark.  Example: `FOR /?`

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` modifiers.

View `for /?` for help help with modifiers and everything about using `for`.

An example:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /R C:\Users\Paul\Pictures %%G IN (*.XMP) do (
    set "data=%%~dpnG"
    echo "!data!"
    echo "!data!.ABC"
    echo "!data!.*"
)
```

`dpn` is drive, path and name.

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix for your existing batch file is too move the find and replace variables before the `FOR` command.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "search=XMP"
set "replace=ABC"
For /R C:\Users\Paul\Pictures %%G IN (*.XMP) do (
    set "data=%%~G"
    set "data=!data:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo !data!
)
```

But as I pointed out in my comments above and what Michael has shown you, if you are just wanting to replace the extension then use the command modifiers as explained in the help file for the `FOR` command.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /R C:\Users\Paul\Pictures %%G IN (*.XMP) do (
    echo %%~dpnG.abc
)
```

Comment: @DS256, if this answer resolved your question then you should click on the check mark next to the answer to mark this question answered.